# References for regional classification

Tags: reference-request, international-economics

I read an [international study, Table 2](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300) and see that the author did **regions*year** fixed effect. I am looking for some reference to classify 64 coutries in their paper to different region.
I found a link [here](https://www.internetworldstats.com/list1.htm#OC) but I think it is better that I have the reference from a paper.

I show the Table 2 of this paper here for facilitating reading
[image]

**Update**
From the [author's description in the footnotes 14](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300)

> We allocate countries into seven geographic regions: **North America,
> Latin America, Western Europe, Central and Eastern Europe, Asia,
> Africa, and Oceania.**

Comment: I saw someone voted that my question should be closed. I hope that if you think my question is not clear or else, please let me know in the comment part that I can edit it more carefully. Thank you so much and namaste.

Comment: Hi! I also find your question unclear. Perhaps it is not self contained, important information is behind the links?

Comment: I also find it unclear, although I wont use my mod vote here. First, what regions did the study use the picture has just countries. Second you just look for any arbitrary unrelated study where someone picked different regions? So if the study decided to do some regions based on continents, and this study did it on subcontinents is that enough or what are other parameters that the study has to satisfy?

Comment: Hi Giskard and 1muflon1, thank you for your help so much, I just have an important update